# Can the Xbox Kinect sensor accurately assess your heart rate across the room?

Tags: medical-science

This [Daily Mail article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2408748/The-sensor-reads-heartbeat-feet-away-WITHOUT-touching-you.html) suggests that the Kinect camera on the xbox is capable of assessing your heart rate from four feet away by detecting changes in the colour of your skin.

Has the accuracy of this claim been proven?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any video camera is capable of this.

[This work by Wu *et al*.](http://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/vidmag/) demonstrates the technique.

> Using our method, we are able to visualize the flow of blood as it fills the face...

Here's a video: http://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/vidmag/video/face-ideal-from-0.83333-to-1-alpha-50-level-4-chromAtn-1.mp4

[Microsoft uses the same or similar method](http://www.forbes.com/sites/matthickey/2013/05/24/source-xbox-ones-heart-sensing-tech-not-microsofts-idea/).